# How to change a Pandas dataframe into feature vector?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with 10 columns, 9 of which are features to be used to predict the 10th column.

How is it ossible to convert this Pandas dataframe into X and y vectors to use in a linear regression problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your dataframe loaded as the variable df, you can simply use this

```
X = df[['A','B','C']]
y = df['Z']
```

where A, B and C are your independent variables and Z is your dependent variable.

Comment: is that possible to use X and  y for train_test_split further?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Please see sklearn's documentation for more  details . Have a look here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
#format the data as a numpy array to feed into the algorithm
X = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Ind1']),np.asarray(df['Ind2']),np.asarray(df['Ind3'])])
y = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Dep'])])
```

Or, simplified.

```
# array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
arr = df.index.to_numpy()

#  array([1, 2, 3])
arr = df['A'].to_numpy()
```